# Is there a word other than "discoverer" for someone who discovers something new in the world?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for something that sounds a little better than "discoverer"

Comment: Could you give us more context or details?

Comment: Or if you just want a synonym that sounds better, I would go with *exhume*. But, again, wether you can use that interchangeably depends on the context.

Comment: What do you mean by "*better*"? Unless you clarify, this question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: @RexYuan: "exhume" is a verb; "discoverer" is a noun, so I'm afraid you haven't answered the question. Also, well... "exhume" does not mean discover. It might mean "UNcover", but only in a bizarre or specialist way.

Comment: The repetition of "er" may look a little strange, but it's the stock-standard word for the concept.

Comment: The most appropriate synonym depends on what the discovered thing is. If it's a new land mass, _explorer_ might be a good choice; if it's a biological relationship, _researcher_ might work. In any event, as RexYuan and Drew have commented above, the question as currently formulated doesn't give prospective answerers enough context to enable them to put together a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I looked up the entry in the Oxford Dictionary of National Biography on Sir Alexander Fleming by Michael Worboys. In its opening paragraph it notes the most important fact about Fleming, namely that he was 'the *discoverer* of penicillin'.

An expression found fitting to Fleming's monumental step (which changed the course of much of twentieth-century medicine) must surely have been the best available to the author. Otherwise he would have used something else.

> Fleming, Sir Alexander (1881–1955), bacteriologist and **discoverer of
>   penicillin**, was born on 6 August 1881, the third of the four children
>   of Hugh Fleming (d. 1888), farmer, of Lochfield, in the parish of
>   Loudoun near Darvel, in Ayrshire, from his second marriage, to Grace
>   Sterling Morton (d. 1928), the daughter of a neighbouring farmer.

Answer (score 0):

**Pioneer**(noun):

> 1) A person who is among the first to research and develop a new area of knowledge or activity.
>   
> 2) A person who is among the first to explore or settle a new country or area.

***Source:***
[oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pioneer)

Comment: Niiice. Spot on. +1.

Comment: I guess I have to disagree with this. "Pioneer" is certainly a related concept, but it sounds really strange to say, "Galileo was the pioneer of Europa," or "James Cook was the pioneer of New Zealand."

Comment: @JasonMelançon "Lessing was the exponent of German classicism; Herder, on the contrary, was a pioneer of the romantic movement." doesn't sound strange to me.

Comment: Pioneer doesn't mean first, it means early. The people who travelled across the US in covered wagons were pioneers, but they certainly weren't the first people - not even the first WASPs - to go there. They didn't discover anything (not even dysentery or cannibalism).